# Was Isserson a good commander on the field?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, strategy

Isserson is one of the fathers of the [deep battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_operation) doctrine and was one of the most brilliant minds of the Soviet Army. (According to Joukov's memoir)

However, Isserson was also described as an awful leader on the field. He lost many exercises during the 30's (Also when Joukov was the CO of an armored division) and he was supposed to have some issue with interpersonal relationships.
Is there any report of his experience on the field to prove his unability to lead men ?

Comment: 1) [Please cite every non-trivial assertion in your question](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/633/1401), (2) [Explain why you question the accepted narrative.](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/922/1401) (3) Have you done any research so far?

Comment: Is Joukov the same as [Zhukov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgy_Zhukov)? WHy is Isserson not even mentioned in the page on Deep Battle?  What research have you done?

Comment: I read the french edition of Joukov's memoir and I found a letter written by Isserson daughter where she explained that Isserson actually won tactical exercises several times. Actually I can not foud any trustworthy  document...

Comment: I could be convinced "won tactical exercises several times" is an example of damning with faint praise.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I think you'll find that [Isserson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_operation#Isserson.3B_the_factor_of_depth) has his own section on the deep battle page.

Comment: I do have to stand corrected on "inability to follow through from defense to attack" for Zhukov, "deep battle" and Stalingrad. That was a very impressive counter offensive...one Von Manstein was waiting for sadly tho. Ended up being a kind of "mechanized Battle of the Wilderness" for the Red Army. HUGE battles with just outrageous death and destruction and about zero to show for it all.